# Spring MVC is not detecting my controllers

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring MVC project with the following files:

> /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
      <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
       <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And 2 configuration files:

> /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <import resource="appconfig-mvc.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="yc.servlets"/>

    <!--<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>-->
</beans>
```

> /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appconfig-mvc.xml

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And the class that contains my controller:

```
package yc.servlets;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class TestPage {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello_there", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

I think this is enough to get a working spring mvc, but when I type `localhost:8888` in browser I get a `404` error.

`localhost:8888/hello_there` also gives `404` error.

Comment: What happens when you access `localhost:8888/hello_there`?

Comment: @GauravRai1512 If it's wrong port, he will get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error instead of 404

Comment: Do you have hello.jsp file ?

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura no.

Comment: Is it right, that your first file you posted here is called /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appconfig-root.xml ? If so please edit the header. Maybe you should use <context:component-scan> element in your appconfig-mvc.xml.

Comment: @sven.kwiotek I put `<context:component-scan>` in my `appconfig-mvc.xml`. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I think sharing your project structure might help.

Comment: How do you build your project? Which (spring) libraries you are using?

Comment: @sven.kwiotek here is my project structure https://imgur.com/104OpOf . I will update the original post and put the maven dependencies that this project uses.

Comment: I see there is the is /WEB-INF/jsp/ defined in your InternalResourceViewResolver bean, but in your structure you have your hello.jsp directly under /webapp. Try create /WEB-INF/jsp/ and move hello.jsp to this corresponding folder.

Comment: @sven.kwiotek still not working...

Comment: Do you have some debug output or stacktrace (log file) ?

Comment: @sven.kwiotek That's the funny part, beside the 404 error in browser I do not get another error. That's the initial output of the program https://pastebin.com/auMN9gPG

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi you are returning "hello" in your controller and its going to find hello.jsp
If it dont find it will throw 404 http error

As you configured your InternalViewResolver :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

It is trying to find  in /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp , so when you are returning String "hello "in  controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello_there", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
```

It will add a suffix ".jsp" to "hello" and it will try to find "hello.jsp" as it could not find it it will throw 404

You can change from your @Controller to @RestController which adds implicitly @ResponseBody annotation and see if it returns "hello" in response

Also if this does not help you can change:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

to this one :

```
<servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

If its still now working try next steps:

Try such url :

```
localhost:8080/yourApplicationName/hello_there
```

default conext-path its your app name here
If you go to TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/

you will find that in root folder there is not your application

So thats why it could not found by localhost:8080/...

You can fix this by two ways:

```
1.Find your application deployed and copy to root folder in 
    TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT
 2.See the name of your application in  TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ 
   and call url : localhost:8080/yourAppName/hello_world
```

Thanks

Comment: It still doesn't work. I created `hello.jsp`, but it still doesn't show anything.

Comment: Nope, localhost:port/myAppName/helloThere gives HTTP Status 404 -

Comment: Please tell me the app name in tomcat_home/webapps directory

Comment: The name is `mywebapp`

Comment: Try to make a call 
localhost:8080/mywebapp/hello_there 
Actually why you are running a port 8888 where did you specified it in tomcat configuration because by default its 8080 
if not , if you ovverrided it use 8888

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183318/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-cristid9).

Answer (score 0):

I've spent more than 5 hours on this issue and the following workaround proved to be successfull.

First, I've changed the `/WEB_INF/web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
      <display-name>  Spring version </display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

And, instead of 2 configuration files, now I have only one file `mvc-servlet-dispatcher.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="yc.servlets" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

With these changes it works.